# JFET RDS(on) Matching

Tags: jfet, rdson

Quick question here - I have a circuit that originally used a 2SK30ATM-GR JFET, with an RDS(on) maximum of 800 ohms. Most of the cheap JFETs I can find have a significantly smaller RDS value, generally below 5 ohms. The application for this JFET is just an audio circuit, so is the RDS value going to affect anything if I substitute in a new JFET?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at JFETs? usually they don't quote an RDS(on) for JFETs. That is for enhancement mode MOSFETs. Idss is a common parameter for JFETs. What devices have you looked at?

Comment: Maybe I just have a bad datasheet for the 2SK30 - the site below states RDS was 800 ohms max. So basically any JFET that meets power ratings will work?

Comment: https://alltransistors.com/mosfet/transistor.php?transistor=14782

Comment: It depends entirely on the circuit it is used in.

Comment: @zvolk4 - The term RDS is not used in the datasheet itself, only in the preamble at the top. That part even calls it a MOSFET whereas the 2SK30 is a JFET. RDS is not  aterm used to compare JFETs. Please give an example of on of the cheap devices you are comparing.

Comment: The data sheet cited shows typical Rds of about 250 ohms (biased with Vgs=0V). Lots of small-signal JFETs have such Rds values - a few might actually still be in production. You won't likely find a JFET with Rds lower than about 40 ohms unless it is a power device (a specialty item).